# how to get selected text of any application into safari to google(AppleScript)

Tags: applescript, selected, selectedtext

how to get selected text of any application into safari to google in AppleScript?

here is the sample code what am trying to do:

```
tell application "System Events" to set selectedText to get selection
     tell application "Safari"
         open location "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & selectedText
         activate
     end tell
end tell
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your issue is. Assuming it's grabbing thE selected text the clipboard might be a useful intermediary. AppleScript  can do Cmd+C.

Comment: Some apps already provide a “Search” option, when you select some text and right-click. If that’s not sufficient, Automator (which is admittedly on its way out) can define Services, and most apps include a Services submenu, so create a service that takes the selected text and passes it to your “search” action. One thing: your AppleScript above needs to percent-escape the text before appending it to the URL. See `-[NSString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:]` which you can call via the AppleScriptObjC bridge.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I wrote the script for a similar task. You might also prefer this approach:

```
tell application "Safari"
    open location "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & selectedText
    activate
end tell

------------------------------- HANDLERS ------------------------------------

on getSelectedText(appName)
    
    tell application appName to activate -- bring application to front
    
    -- get selected text, if it is selected
    set the clipboard to "" 
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "c" using command down
    set {aSelection, maxTimeOut} to {"", 0}
    repeat while aSelection is ""
        set maxTimeOut to maxTimeOut + 0.1
        if maxTimeOut > 1 then error "NOTHING SELECTED."
        set aSelection to (the clipboard) as text
    end repeat
    
    return aSelection

end getSelectedText

on encode_URL(txt)
    set python_script to ¬
        "import sys, urllib; print urllib.quote(sys.argv[1])"
    set python_script to "/usr/bin/python -c " & ¬
        quoted form of python_script & " " & ¬
        quoted form of txt
    return do shell script python_script
end encode_URL
```

Comment: This does not restore the state of the _clipboard_ property in all cases, **e.g. before** `{{«class furl», 37}, {«class icns», 934610}, {«class ut16», 24}, {«class utf8», 11}, {«class 8BPS», 1772194}, {GIF picture, 124016}, {«class jp2 », 213483}, {JPEG picture, 98649}, {TIFF picture, 4198020}, {«class PNGf», 532524}, {«class BMP », 4194358}, {«class TPIC», 1132853}, {Unicode text, 22}, {string, 11}}`, **e.g. after** `{{Unicode text, 22}, {string, 11}, {scrap styles, 22}, {«class utf8», 11}, {«class ut16», 24}, {scrap styles, 22}}` **thus destroying what was originally on the _clipboard_.**

Comment: In another, but different, use case it also can take a long time to execute completely if there is a larger amount of _graphic data_ on the _clipboard_. As an example, it took 1 minute 50 seconds to execute because I had just previously used **⌃⇧⌘4** to copy the selected area to the _clipboard_ to then paste into a graphic image program. IMO It's a poor practice to save/restore the clipboard in this manner without using some control statements added to the workflow, and/or instead use a _clipboard manager_ if needing to save/restore the _clipboard_ is important to ones workflow.

Comment: @robert thanks for your reply. The way to use clipboard is not work for me. i have an clipboard record app and don't want to affect the app's behaviour. Is there any other way?

Comment: @Lucas, **you are going to copy your selection automatically without affecting the clipboard.** It's impossible. You were intimidated by another user with their comments. They loves it. All clipboard operations are sequential, so I'll remove restoring content from my answer. So that you are not frightened by different "clever" people.

Comment: @Robert, actually the app "betterTouchTool" has a function "google with selectedText". which exactly what i want to figure it out. it can read the selected text in any app and then trigger shortcut key to google it without affecting the clipboard.